# Looking for roots of the Kobi family of Romanshorn and Winterthur, Switzerland

Tags: birth-records, marriage-records, switzerland

Elisabeth (Kobi) Conaway, daughter of Ernst Kobi and Klara Merz, immigrated to the U.S. The family has no further information.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than just posting a broad request for any information.

Comment: A more focused question might be to describe your search for their immigration record and then ask whether anyone knows where else you could look.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Swiss Historic dictionary](https://hls-dhs-dss.ch/famn/index.php), there was Kobi families in two swiss municipalities prior to 1800 :

- [Rapperswil (BE)](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/35222712)
- [Münchenbuchsee (BE)](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1682567)

Note that both of those places are almost neighbouring, so the most likely is that the "nest" of Kobis came from here, and then they went living elsewere in Switzerland.

In 1949, a Kobi family bought the [bourgeoisie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_bourgeoisie) (just to be clear, this has nothing to do with marxism) in Wintertur, but that family was originally from Rapperswil (BE). Back then the rules for having bourgeoisies were set high, so it's very likely the family was living in Wintertur since a long time.(*)

Merz is a very common name so it could be from almost anywhere.

(*) For example my own family bought the bourgeoisie in a municipality in 1947(**), but they lived there since 1920.

(**) a fact I also learned thanks to the Swiss Historic Dictionary